# Can I force a WebMethod to use port 80 in a .asmx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I have a Flash object using a `WebMethod` in a public class implementing `System.Web.Services.WebService`.

This works fine in development but in the staging environment the `.asmx` is telling the Flash to use the internal port of the web server within the network, which does not work.

Can I specify that the `WebMethod` must use port 80?

This has not been an issue for JQuery functions consuming other WebMethods in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The port number is specfied in the url, e.g. http://domain.com:80/mywebservice.asmx/mymethod

As long as the webserver is configured to accept traffic on that port, it should work just like any other url.

Comment: In this case the port number is the internal network port of the server, rather than 80 and we don't seem to be able to set it back to 80 in the Flash object.